# Remove leading 0 in String with letters and digits

Tags: regex, oracle, sed, regex-group, regexp-replace

I have a comma separated file where I need to change the first column removing leading zeroes in string. Text file is as below

```
ABC-0001,ab,0001

ABC-0010,bc,0010
```

I need to get the data as under

```
ABC-1,ab,0001   

ABC-10,bc,0010
```

I can do a command line replace which i tried as below:

```
sed  's/ABC-0*[1-9]/ABC-[1-9]/g' file
```

I ended up getting output:

```
ABC-[1-9],ab,0001

ABC-[1-9]0,ac,0010
```

Can you please tell me what I am missing in here.

Alternately I also tried to apply formatting in the SQL that generates this file as below:

```
select regexp_replace(key,'((0+)|1-9|0+)','(1-9|0+)') from file  where key in ('ABC-0001','ABC-0010')
```

which gives output as

```
ABC-(1-9|0+)1
ABC-(1-9|0+)1(1-9|0+)
```

Help on either of solution will be very helpful!

Comment: see also https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions...

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
sed -E 's/ABC-0*([1-9])/ABC-\1/g' file
                ------      --
                 |           | 
         capturing group     |
                          captured group
```

Comment: Nice ASCII graphics for illustrating the concepts.

Answer (score 2):

To do it in the query using Oracle, where the key value with the zeroes you want to remove is in a column called "key" in a table called "file", would look like this:

```
select regexp_replace(key, '(-)(0+)(.*)', '\1\3')
from file;
```

You need to capture the dash as it is "consumed" by the regex as it is matched.  Followed by the second group of one or more 0's, followed by the rest of the field.  Replace with captured groups 1 and 3, leaving the 0's (if any) between out.